# gsutil and large quantity uploads

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a big directory (1TB) with thousands of 'small' files (gsutil -m cp -R -q /dir/* gs://bucket_name). But after a couple of hours I can see the CPU usage skyrocketing to 100% and the network traffic dropping to 0 permanently. Seems to get stuck at "Catching up md5 for resumed upload" on a random file who's md5sum should take less than a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a fix for this problem now, in gsutil release 3.18. You can get it
by running:

gsutil update

Please let us know if you continue to have problems after applying this update.